# Weave takes my node offline when I hit a container's ip

Tags: azure, networking, docker, kubernetes, weave

I'm running weave with kubernetes/cni . I have a wordpress/mysql pod running on a kube minion. When I hit the url of the wordpress service via the browser, my node goes down (on azure). I upgraded to 8cores and 14gb ram and now when I do hit the wordpress url I find that I can't access the internet i.e. curl google.com which I could do before hitting the wordpress url.

I was curious so I `tail -f /var/log/syslo`g and found the following which may be relevant; Please note I have an nginx pod on the same node and I can access it's url without incident, however the following happens when I hit the wordpress installation page:

```
Jul 21 16:38:27 sc-minion-1 kernel: [ 6319.723678] device vethwepl4fe8074 entered promiscuous mode
Jul 21 16:38:27 sc-minion-1 kernel: [ 6319.732271] eth0: renamed from vethwepg4fe8074
Jul 21 16:38:27 sc-minion-1 systemd-udevd[8388]: Could not generate persistent MAC address for vethwepl4fe8074: No such file or directory
Jul 21 16:38:27 sc-minion-1 kernel: [ 6319.744321] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethwepl4fe8074: link is not ready
Jul 21 16:38:27 sc-minion-1 kernel: [ 6319.744661] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethwepl4fe8074: link becomes ready
Jul 21 16:38:27 sc-minion-1 kernel: [ 6319.744730] weave: port 3(vethwepl4fe8074) entered forwarding state
Jul 21 16:38:27 sc-minion-1 kernel: [ 6319.744736] weave: port 3(vethwepl4fe8074) entered forwarding state
Jul 21 16:38:27 sc-minion-1 docker[883]: time="2016-07-21T16:38:27.987193241Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /images/nginx/json returned error: No such image: nginx"
Jul 21 16:38:27 sc-minion-1 kubelet[2088]: I0721 16:38:27.987696    2088 provider.go:91] Refreshing cache for provider: *credentialprovider.defaultDockerConfigProvider
Jul 21 16:38:28 sc-minion-1 kernel: [ 6320.564156] IPv6: eth0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::3c2b:b1ff:fe47:fe26 detected!
Jul 21 16:38:42 sc-minion-1 kernel: [ 6334.748036] weave: port 3(vethwepl4fe8074) entered forwarding state
Jul 21 16:38:42 sc-minion-1 docker[883]: time="2016-07-21T16:38:42.988502303Z" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
Jul 21 16:38:42 sc-minion-1 docker[883]: time="2016-07-21T16:38:42.988545804Z" level=error msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"
Jul 21 16:39:02 sc-minion-1 docker[883]: time="2016-07-21T16:39:02.989940573Z" level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: Network timed out while trying to connect to https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/nginx/images. You may want to check your internet connection or if you are behind a proxy."
```

Comment: this question is rather old, but did you eventually resolve it?

Comment: It was a while back..I think it was a network connectivity issue or it was that the resolve conf in the containers was off or sth..don't really remember too well, sorry about that